# Использование LAN в приложениях

Tags: c#, python, теория, lan

Есть несколько компов которые объединены одной локальной сетью через маршрутизатор. Каждый из них должен отправлять данные на один комп. Как минимум отправка запросов к БД, в идеале отправка обрабатываемых комманд.

Я хотел бы узнать как это реализовать в теории. Но в примере: Клиенты C#. Сервер обрабатывающий запросы на Python. Примеры из java или c++ помогут толкнуться в нужном направлении, поэтому такая информация также будет полезна.

Comment: А чем отличается lan от wan? Ну есть у вас группа компьютеров с адресами 192.168.1.*, в чем проблема при подключение к локальному адресу? Соединению Client->Server без разницы куда вы подключаетесь, главное чтоб сервер разрешал доступ к локальному адресу.

Comment: Отличие в скорости как я думаю

Comment: Да, но суть подключения это не меняет. Вот есть у вас база, скажем MySQL, висит на компе с внешним адресом 555.555.55.55, вы спокойно подключаетесь через клиент к этому адресу. Если же вы в локальной сети с этим компьютером, то вы также без труда подключитесь и через 192.168.1.1, через его локальный адрес, сути подключения ведь это не меняет. Другой вопрос открыт ли доступ у данного сервера через локальную сеть, а так.. Я лично не понимаю о чем вы тут спрашиваете и что хотите реализовать. Подключение, оно и в Африке подключение...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поищите по запросы Client Server app Python, Client Server app C#, вообще ваш вопрос очень общий, в каждом языке есть библиотеки для работы с сетью, в некоторых языках даже стандартная библиотека содержит такие методы. Вам надо выбрать протокол tcp/udp, в зависимости от этого по разному будет устанавливаться соединение, точнее для udp оно не будет устанавливаться, а как вы по сети будете команды для исполнения передавать это уже сами придумайте) можете строчку которую надо выполнить передать и на принимающей стороне просто исполнить её.

Comment: Для того чтобы вопрос был конкретнее я написал про языки, А уточнее про lan было дано потомучто в моем предположении при использовании специализированных библиотек для LAN программа будет работать быстрее.